# Peel & stick tiles for temporary floor covering over chip board?

Tags: flooring, floor, vinyl-flooring

We recently had a toilet tank crack.  I caught it within two hours. stripped the carpet and foam underlay from the affected hallway, vacuumed up the water, and had a fan on the chip board all within an hour.  I have a slight amount of swelling on one seam -- about a mm.

Next winter we are planning to redo all the floors -- carpet to laminate -- in this  part of the house.

I have a couple of boxes of peel and stick tile from another project.  Directions are very specific that 'porridge board' is not a suitable underlay.

I don't expect it to last for years.  Just for a few months.

Is this a bad idea?  Should I just give the chip board a couple coats of paint?

Comment: Perhaps a cheap bit of lanoleum would be a decent alternative.

Comment: What is listed as a suitable substrate?

Comment: What subfloor are we talking about here? "Porridge board" and "chip board" aren't industry terms we can work with.

Comment: Chip board is made from flakes about 2 to 6 mm in sizes. Sawdust board is made up of stuff 1 mm and smaller.  Porridge board is any pressed wood product that has very little tolerance for water.  OSB = oriented strand board comes in two finishes:  pressed and sanded.  Pressed is used for side wall sheathing and tolerates intermittent wetting for several months.  Sanded is used as sub floor, and is usually rated at 90 days weather exposure.

Answer (score 1):

I have peel and stick tile in several closets on particle board. But it sounds like you may have Oriented Strand Board (visible chips) which is not as smooth on the surface, and that might make a difference.

Closets are low-traffic, which is why I was willing to use P&S at all, but it was a definite improvement from the nasty old carpet removed and the bare particle board left when the carpet was gone. You'll need to address the raised area around the seam in some way, perhaps sanding.

I think it would be worth a try if you do a careful job, since you have the material on hand (sounds like "as excess.")